# Eclipse Oxygen C++ Hello World Cross GCC error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, mingw

so I've been wanting to learn C++ and I just got a new computer. I downloaded Eclipse Oxygen, had some trouble getting it running, but it all works fine now. I tried to write a hello world right off the bat, and there was a gcc and g++ error. I looked it up and got MinGW GCC and it shows up in C++ Project tool paths, but if I hit the 'Hello World' project the box where the different toolpaths show up is completely white and when I continue to the project there is the same gcc error as before. I know this wouldn't happen if I chose MinGW GCC, but I don't have that option when I pick the 'Hello World' project. ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have added MINGW To the Path Environment Variable
2. When your creating a eclipse project - disable the show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform.